# How to .htaccess RewriteRule?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i'm trying to make this address:

http://www.mysite.co.uk/Listing/London/34

really look for: http://www.mysite.co.uk/Listing/listed.php?area=London&list=34
behind the scenes.

I tried this ReWrite in the htacess file in "Listing" folder but it dosen't work:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)$ /listed.php?area=$1&list=$2 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a relative substitution path instead:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)$ listed.php?area=$1&list=$2 [NC,L]
```

It can also be possible that you’re not allowed to use .htaccess files besides in the document root directory.

Comment: @Tom: Do you have the obligatory `RewriteEngine on`?

Comment: @Tom: Then what happens instead?

Comment: @Gumbo you were right.. the slash was the problem! removed it and now it works! thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you only need to remove the `^` from the beginning and change the destination from `/listed.php` to `/Listing/listed.php`